# When shall one use CFTRACE vs CFLOG?

Tags: logging, coldfusion

Just learnt that `<CFTRACE>` can be turned off easily by disabling "Enable Request Debugging Output" in CF Admin.

I found this interesting, would it be okay to leave `<CFTRACE>` tags in production given that "Enable Request Debugging Output" is disabled?

I think log level of `<CFLOG>` can be changed in some neo* xml, can the same be done with `<CFTRACE>`?

In general, when shall one use `<CFLOG>` vs `<CFTRACE>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe CFTRACE was designed to leave in production code because of the ability to only enable it when debugmode is active.  It's nice being able to turn it on selectively when trying to catch one of those bugs you can't seem to replicate in dev.

I use CFLOG more for "real-time" data catching.  I enable it selectively/temporarily to catch data-related bugs where it is unexpected inputs causing issues.  I enable it permanently for catching non-critical errors (functions where you want something to keep processing if it fails without notifying the user) but you want to catch the error and any helpful information in a log file.

And I can't talk about CFLOG without giving more props to Ray Camden for his blog post on using it in his dev process, along with serializeJSON to catch complex variables: [Ray Camden - Another CFLOG/JSON Tip](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/10/4/Another-CFLOGJSON-Tip)

Comment: was it really designed to be used this way?  Nice to know.  I have never used trace since recently.

Comment: Well, I haven't spoken with the architects of ColdFusion MX (that introduced this tag), but the concept of "tracers" is pretty established coding practice.  CFTRACE just makes it easier to track data through an app and keeps the impact on production minimal.  (I highly recommend reading "The Pragmatic Programmer" for more on Tracer Bullet coding, and lots of other great concepts.)

Comment: CFTrace doesn't work when invoked as webservice, `Variable DEBUGGER is undefined.`  and I cannot use MXUnit with Eclipse with CFTRACE

Comment: Henry, I remember reading about that issue.  Apparently it is a verified CF bug and has been submitted.  https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3041451